# How to validate empty form fields

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How can I check that some form fields are empty before submitting it and display an alert.

This is necessary due to the fact that some fields are hidden by v-show

Example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<header>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</header>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" id="idTest">
    <form action="" onsubmit="return false" @submit="foo()">
      <input v-show="false" type="text" required placeholder="required">
      <input type="text" required placeholder="required">
      <button type="submit" onsubmit="alert('works')">send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

<script>

  const app = {
    mounted() {
      document.getElementById("idTest").value = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    },
    methods: {
      foo() {
        alert("works");
      }
    }
  }

  Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app');
</script>
```

Comment: You "example" is a mess, None of your methods or event functions works. Anyway: `The difference is that an element with v-show will always be rendered and remain in the DOM; v-show only toggles the display CSS property of the element.` So you can literary fetch it with any document query and check is it empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) attribute on the input and check if its empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind v-model to inputs, and then check inside submit function, if they are empty or not. Use v-if as well. Also as someone else said, your code looks really messy.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <header>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    </header>

    <body>
      <div id="app">
        <input type="text" id="idTest">
        <form action="" onsubmit="return false" @submit="foo()">
          <input v-if="false" v-model="inputField" type="text" required placeholder="required">
          <input type="text" required placeholder="required">
          <button type="submit" onsubmit="alert('works')">send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </body>

    <script>

      const app = {
        mounted() {
          document.getElementById("idTest").value = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        },
        data() {
          return {
            inputField: ""
        }
      },
        methods: {
          foo() {
            if(this.inputField.length < 1) {
              alert("input is empty")
            }
          }
        }
      }

      Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app');
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 function required(inputtx) 
   {
     if (inputtx.value.length == 0)
      { 
         alert("message");      
         return false; 
      }     
      return true; 
    }
```